# CSS select all, selecting some, but not all elements?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a site which will have no border radius on any element, and rather than using `outline: 0;` multiple times in my stylesheet I'm trying to use the `*` selector to apply `outline: 0;` to everything;

```
* {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  outline: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius:0;
}
```

This CSS works on some elements such as input fields but not buttons.

I am using bootstrap and then including my own stylesheet afterwards.
There are no other instances of `border-radius` in my stylesheet.

Why are there round borders and outlines like this?[image: input fields are styled but buttons are not]

Comment: for that you have to apply `outline:0` to button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to [specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity). The `*` selector itself has a specificity score of 0, 0, 0.

Buttons with focus in Bootstrap have the following selector:

```css
.btn:focus { ... }
```

This has a specificity score of 0, 1, 1, meaning this declaration will override the `*` declaration no matter where in the stylesheet its placed.

This is one of the few cases where `!important` could justifiably be used; if you're not wanting to do that though, you'll need to find all the cases where this declaration doesn't override Bootstrap and add those selectors in to your selector sequence:

```css
*,
.btn:focus { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `!important` with every property for the specific thing which u need to overwrite. I think it'll work...

Use updated code:

```
* {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  outline: 0;
  outline: none!important;
  border-radius:0!important;
}
```

Comment: *Need*? `!important` is never something you should *need* to do.

Comment: Yeah I agree with what you said then the best alternative for the same is that one should individually hide the **`border-radius`** in the specific **`class`** for which we are using the **`border-radius`** and other property.